# Summing value differences across date range

Tags: sql-server-2008

My table is defined as follows:

```
DATETIME             ENERGY VALUE
01/01/2013 00:00:00          1000
           ...
01/01/2013 08:00:00          2000
           ...
06/30/2013 00:00:00         10000
           ...
06/30/2013 08:00:00         12000
```

I need to calculate total energy value between: start hour of 00:00:00 and end hour 08:00:00 in a single day then sum these values for date range between 01/01/2013 and 06/30/2013.
Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: please give input and desired output for it, for me problem either unclear or too easy to ask about it on the SO

Comment: Please show us your current SQL statement and we can point out the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

SELECT SUM(DAILYENERGYSUM)
FROM
(SELECT SUM(ENGERGY) as DAILYENERGYSUM
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATEPART(DATETIME) >= '1/1/2013' and DATEPART(DATETIME) <= '6/30/2013' and TIMEPART(DATETIME) >= 0 and TIMEPART(DATETIME) <= 8
GROUP BY DATEPART(DATETIME)) AS DAYSUMS